# How can i use my ImageArray extend JPanel class into another class extend JApplet

Tags: java, arrays, swing

My programmer was to make a program that translate each word you enter into another languages and shows the image of each word enter.
The translator of English words into french Words by using Jfield and StringArray works. But i got a big problem for setting each images. I don't know how to call them in JApplet Class.

The goal is to use ImageArray class for setup each image corresponding to each world enter in Jfield.

THis is my ImageArray class:

### Heading1

public class ImageArray extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

```
Image[] pics;

String[] names;

int NUM_PICS;

JPanel controls, imagePanel;
JButton randomize;

Image currentImage;

ImageIcon icon;
JLabel imageLabel;

public ImageArray() {

    setImages();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    loadImages();

    currentImage=pics[0];

    setUpControls();
    setUpImagePanel();


}


public void setUpControls(){
    controls=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    randomize=new JButton("randomize");
    randomize.addActionListener(this);
    controls.add(randomize);
    add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void setUpImagePanel(){
    imagePanel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    imageLabel=new JLabel();
    imageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    icon=new ImageIcon();
    icon.setImage(currentImage);
    imageLabel.setIcon(icon);

    imagePanel.add(imageLabel);

    add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}



public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.drawImage(currentImage,0,0,250,250,this);


}



public void setImages(){

    pics = new Image[NUM_PICS];
    NUM_PICS=names.length;


    names[0]= "apple.jpg";
    names[1]= "bags.jpg";
    names[2] = "bathroom.jpg";
    names[3] = "battled.jpg";
    names[4]= "car.png";
    names[5]= "chairs.jpg";
    names[6] = "Computer.jpg";
    names[7] = "family.jpg";
    names[8] = "flowers.jpg";
    names[9] = "god.jpg";
    names[10] = "house.png";
    names[11] = "map.jpg";
    names[12] = "men.jpg";
    names[13] = "pencil.jpg";
    names[14] = "sisters.jpg";
    names[15] = "tomato.jpg";
    names[16] = "watch.jpg";
    names[17] = "women.jpg";
    names[18] ="book.gif";

}

public void loadImages(){
    for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++){

        currentImage=pics[NUM_PICS];
        icon.setImage(currentImage);
        repaint();
    }
}



public int indexOfImages(ImageIcon userInput)

{

    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        if(userInput.equals(names[i])){return i;}

    }
    return -1;
}




@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object button=e.getSource();

    if(button==randomize){
        int random=(int)(Math.random()*pics.length);
        currentImage=pics[random];
        icon.setImage(currentImage);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). ..

Comment: .. 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 4) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 5) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: someone can help me please

Comment: sorry for all my stupid mistake i am not good at all in program

Comment: someone can see what i wrote i made a new one

Comment: please try to read